# Are questions about following style guides considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

For those not aware, [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/) is a style guide for how to name elements in CSS.  I follow the [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass) tag exclusively, so most of the questions I see are along the lines of "how can I make Sass generate this SMACSS-style selector?"  These questions seem perfectly reasonable to me.  Every once in a while, a question will pop up that's more along the lines of "what is the proper way to name my element according to the SMACSS rules?"

I have always viewed the second type of question as being off-topic in the same way I would view any question that's about how to name things or format code.  However, looking over the other questions in the [smacss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smacss) tag, they seem to be considered acceptable by the community unless the question is *really* opinion based.

Are such questions considered on-topic?

Related:

- [Is it OK to ask for a "word-choice" on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277500/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-a-word-choice-on-stack-overflow)
- [Are questions about naming classes relevant on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121289/are-questions-about-naming-classes-relevant-on-stack-exchange)
- [Is it OK to ask a question about naming conventions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90637/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-question-about-naming-conventions)

Comment: I wouldn't say they're opinion based, if somewhere in the SMACSS guideline, someone could find a definitive answer and provide it. Whether or not they make good questions is a different issue.