# Are "What is this thing called?" questions on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

In a recent question on Stack Overflow, the user was asking for the proper name for a concept, so that they could further research the topic (on their own). We all know how difficult it is to search for something when you don't even know what it is called.

My initial feeling is that this is more suited to Stack Overflow chat rather than as a question. But I'd like to get an authoritative opinion to make sure. Can someone pitch in?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6586/31260

Comment: related [Is it OK to ask for a "word-choice" on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277500)

Comment: It depends how directly programming-related the term is/isn't. See [Is the “What is AM/PM called?” question on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363454/is-the-what-is-am-pm-called-question-on-topic)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question asks about choosing a name for a variable or similar. This is about finding the proper name for a concept.

Answer (score 16):

A well worded and researched "what is this called" question would be fine as far as I'm concerned.

That said, such a question would be very hard to construct. Many are duplicates ("What is % in C#?"), especially when they are about syntax. Syntax questions are also easily answered by sufficient research.

For *non* syntax questions, it can be acceptable.

Answer (score 10):

From old MSO (now MSE): [What is the appropriate / preferred method for questions concerning programming nomenclature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203880/213963)

[Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) says thus:

> "What is the name of this thing" questions are off-topic on both Stack
> Overflow and Programmers.
>
> These are poor questions for the same reasons that "identify this
> obscure TV show, film or book by its characters or story" are bad
> questions: you can't Google them, they aren't practical in any way,
> they don't help anyone else, and allowing them opens the door for the
> asking of other types of marginal questions.
>
> **See Also**   [Let's Play the Guessing Game](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game)

and has a comment on it:

> Their answers also tend to be exemplars of the bikeshedding phenomenon, attracting giddy upvotes and comments like "+1 I didn't know about this!" "Thanks, cool to learn something!", and so on. –  [Josh Caswell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/159251/josh-caswell) [Nov 1 '13 at 18:42](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203880/what-is-the-appropriate-preferred-method-for-questions-concerning-programming#comment650447_203884)

I find that this answer is still most appropriate and authoritative today on the subject, especially in the context of Stack Overflow.

---

On Programmers.SE: [On the troubles of naming and terminology](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology) I attempt to provide some guidelines for what *could* be an acceptable question (there is also a few links in the question for tracking the history of such questions):

> These questions are **marginally** on topic.  However, these questions
> are often poor and without additional information they should be
> closed as too broad or primarily opinion.
>
> We have exactly the same problem that English.SE does with their own
> single word requests - lots of them, low quality, uninteresting,
> attract poor answers from users, and they get complained about in
> chat, they attract less active users and repel more active users.
>
> Drawing from [English.SE tag:
> single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests)
> and [Against single word
> requests](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests)
> there is a set of questions that are necessary to make these questions
> better:
>
> - **Describe exactly the context that the name or terminology is used**
>
>   - Programming language - the same concept can be used in multiple ways.  As I point out in
>     [Why is this question wrong? (asking for the name of a specific practice)](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6296/why-is-this-question-wrong-asking-for-the-name-of-a-specific-practice/6297#6297)
>     and ultimately
>     [How is it called when you define constants that simply refer to a large namespace?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/219323/40980)
>     there is sometimes no standard way to handle this across *all*
>     programming languages.
>   - Code example - without a demonstration of what the code is to do, multiple terms can be used for the same thing.
> - **Describe the criteria for acceptance**
>
>   - Without some criteria for acceptance of the term, there is no way to say which one is better than another and the question is simply
>     a poll for people to toss out suggestions for a name.
> - **Which names/terms have you thought of and discarded as inappropriate?**
>
>   - Just asking for a name doesn't let us know which direction you have thought and as described in
>     [Why is research important?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6559/40980)
>     we need to know what you have already thought of and discarded.
> - **Does the question show that you searched for a suitable word before asking the question?**
>
>   - Without the information to show that you *have* tried, such questions reek of intellectual laziness.  The use of Google is not
>     hard.  Sometimes these words are right there if you just enter the
>     language of choice and the code construct you are working with.  Stack
>     exchange is not and should never be a "I don't know, I'll ask what its
>     called on P.SE and see if anyone answers"
>
> Given the above pieces of information being provided in the question,
> it *might* be acceptable to keep the question open.
>
> I also *strongly* want people to look at the English.SE tags:
> https://english.stackexchange.com/tags and note that
> single-word-requests on that site make up an average of 30/week or
> about 1/5<sup>th</sup> of all of their questions on a day to day
> basis.
>
> Do we, P.SE, want to have a similar bit of 1/5th of our questions be
> questions about what to name some 'pattern' or what a particular
> structure is called within some code?

---

I will note that I *do* hope that this is a rather high bar... though most of the questions of naming that I've seen tend to be trying to do the limbo with "how low can you go?"

Comment: *"that "identify this obscure TV show, film or book by its characters or story" are bad questions"*. Yet, we got that anyway. Examples: *[What is the title of this old interstellar travel guide?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59601)*, *[1970s to 1980s space exploration short story from an anthology](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36420)* and *[Boy born in space needing to somersault and spin to counteract earth's rotation](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41273)*. They even have [a tag](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) for this purpose.

Comment: Stack Exchange site "Movies & TV" has [a similar tag](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie).

Comment: @PeterMortensen and [they feel that it has problems with them...](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1987/5901) almost 4 years later.