# Asking questions but not knowing the correct terminology to find the answer originally

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, help-improvement, terminology

I'm very much new to using VBA or any sort of coding; however, since finishing university last year, I've found that many of the functions needed for my job require me to develop some VBA to run through Excel.

It was because of this that I came across Stack Overflow and it has been a huge help.

However there has been one area which has caused me some frustration and disappointment.

This is when I've asked a questions at times it has been down voted and discredited due to the question having been already answered. Now when it came to asking this question I searched the topics which I thought were my problem and could not find a solution. Due to me lacking the technical knowledge, I was unable to find an answer to what I wanted; I was looking in the wrong places.

So my question here is twofold:

- Firstly is there any advice on how to find out what sort of wording one should search when answering questions?
- Secondly should there be more constructive advice given to those of us who don't fully understand what we are looking for in able to help us develop?

Finally I should stress that every time I've learnt something from this website I've taken it on board and tried to adapt it to different situations and understand how it works, just so I don't get accused of trying to get people to do my work for me when it is just starting completely from scratch.

Comment: To be honest, SO is not meant for giving tutorials, training, basic learning etc. The Q/A format doesn't fit well on that content. You should rely on other resources to get the grips of how stuff named in your programing language. On the plus-side: for VBA there is plenty available.

Comment: Thanks for the honesty i appreciate it. On a side note are there any particularly good resources you might recommend based on personal experience.

Comment: I haven't followed a VBA training but google gives a lot of results. You might consider checking pluralsight.com if you are looking for online-courses.

Comment: If your question is in the form of, "What's the programming term for [something]?", You might try looking at the [terminology] and [software] tags at [English Language & Usage SE.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software). You will want to check out [what's on topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking there. In particular, naming for classes and variables is off topic.

Comment: If you're asking what's essentially a duplicate question, but you're not using any of the same keywords, then downvoting for lack of research effort seems a little unfair. If you think you need a "foo", and you need a "bar", then you're probably not going to find anything useful no matter how much research you do. The main point of closing as a duplicate is to expand the number of search terms that lead to the information people need.

Comment: You don't seem to have any questions that have been downvoted so I imagine you've deleted them now, but in the ones that were, did you show that research effort? Generally, I try to refrain from downvoting if the user shows what they have searched for - be that a link that is close but not quite right (as well as why it isn't) or just search terms that didn't result in any results

Comment: @Sayse, i removed the one which had been down voted as they'd posted a link to the question where it had been answered. And i hadn't shown the research effort to brilliantly i'll admit, partially because my research didn't pick anything that solved my problem. I'll bear that in mind for future reference though to always show what i've found but explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Being marked as a duplicate doesn't *necessarily* mean that you shouldn't have asked the question or your question was bad. Duplicates are marked because another question contains a helpful answer, but having multiple questions written differently pointing to the same valid answer is actually useful for helping more people to find the correct answer for their issue. That doesn't necessarily mean that all users think about that when they flag a duplicate.

Comment: Related:[Are "What is this thing called?" questions on-topic for Stack Overflow? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277508/are-what-is-this-thing-called-questions-on-topic-for-stack-overflow?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When your reputation is more than 20, you can turn to the chat for advice. There are a lot of knowledgeable people whom are very willing to help you as long as you've made an effort and ask politely and accept that people might have other things to do than to tend to your questions.

**I have the same issue as you being new, and I'm gonna share with you what I do:**

#### English is the universal language for programming

Most of us are not native English speakers and a lot of us have turned to resources in our native languages either by choice or by the school's. If this is true in your cases, try to pick up a book on the topic in English. Sometimes all you need is a quick tutorial, sometimes it's the extensive guide.

#### RTFM - Read the * manual

This may come off as rude, but if you're new to a programming language, at least familiarize yourself with the documentation and/or read at least one beginner level book on the subject. How could you know about things when you don't even know the very basics yet?

#### Find the XY

If language isn't the issue, only newbieness, then your first step is to identify the problem, without knowing the terminology try to find what it is you actually want to do, don't search on the things you know of. I still recommend you read through a book on the subject to get some glossary. It will come as you learn more.

#### Retry as many times as you need

Try to rephrase your question many times. StackOverflow has been around for a long time now and accessed by thousands (if not over a milion) developers from around the globe, there's very few topics - especially for a newb - that hasn't been asked and answered yet. Eventually you will find someone who phrased it in the same way you would.

#### Don't rely solely on Google

StackOverflow has an abundance of resources dedicated to help you find similar topics. When you try to write a question, it will automatically suggest similar question to you based on your title. You will find suggestions to your right when you're browsing SO on similar topics/questions. Use those functions.

#### Search the tags

If you have some kind of idea of what your question is about, use the tags to find questions on that topic.

#### Learn to debug

This might not be relevant to you right now, but SO is not a "please debug my code for me" site. Learning to debug is one of the most important skills you need to have as a developer. There will be bugs, and you WILL have to deal with them. Do **yourself** the favor of learning to debug.

---

Finally, I want to let you know that there is a more advanced way of searching SO and I recommend you have a look at the [help center's guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: Maybe add to this that if you're using an Integrated Development Environment or other tools that enable you to debug/step-through/inspect its state, know how to use those tools.

Comment: I added a section about debugging. It's something very important to know and very often the issues one has are bug-related.

Comment: The XY problem is a great observation.

Comment: @rene: Though there's a danger to stepping through a program in order to get to know what it does: Observation influences events. Also, it's a skill to know what observed behavior is contractual (and thus stable under optimization / change of environment) and which isn't (and might thus change just before your presentation).

Comment: That is true @Deduplicator ... but not so much in VBA and the 'IDE' that comes with it...so in this case my over simplified world holds...

Comment: Debugging is mostly mentioned by me because a) it's important and b) A LOT of questions from new members are "My code doesn't work, here is my big fat code-dump, find out what's wrong and fix it for me" sometimes ending with a please or thanks.

Comment: @JohnSnow great answer btw very informative and very useful. Also i'll admit one of the things i had asked question wise was when i had an idea of overall how it worked, but couldn't understand how to tweak it to work in my document or with multiple pages. Thankfully once somebody explains this once it transfers to other times you need it quite nicely, just sometimes you need help getting your head around how the code works.

Comment: RTFM - read the fantastic manual. Why is that rude?

Comment: Some people just don't like to be told what to do I suppose ;P

Comment: Most chats I've been in on SO are the most toxic place on the internet.

Comment: I've had no issues with any chat on SO or SE so far. Be polite, try to write as proper English as you can, and read the room's rules (if there are any) before you post your question. The chat isn't your personal support, but people are quite helpful.

Comment: I wanted to say "You know nothing, @JohnSnow", but that's actually a really nice answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

My advice ask other co-workers first.  Ideally, you have a mentor who will help you learn the basic knowledge and terminology.  If this fails, try to find the tutorials online for yourself.  Really, there's no good way for SO to help you unless you have a certain (low) initial experience with programming.  The only advice we can give is "learn the basics" which is an inherently unhelpful answer.

Once you have that base knowledge, you should have a much easier time finding the answers to your questions.  If you still can't find enough, your questions should now at least be on-topic now that you have a base grasp of what you need accomplished.

Comment: The only issues with that are that I work in marketing and so the rest of the team so to speak have no experience really of programming. I seem to have been given it as the "new boy" so learning as i go. I have been watching tutorials and trying to pick up a few things and I am learning slowly.

Comment: lol 'I work in marketing' - you do realize that you are the enemy, right? :)

Comment: @Ben0708 well hopefully you get to a point where you can adequately express your problems _to other programmers_ (that is a challenge).  On another note, there might be other non-programming solutions to your problems.  Super User can help with some of those.

Comment: Haha the ones you might work with possibly, I hope not to be an enemy to many people :). But yeah ideally i would like to get to that stage, spending a lot of time outside of work reading as much as i can to develop the skills. Thanks for your time btw

Answer (score 4):

I want to add some relevant VBA-specific information to @JohnSnow's excellent answer:

**Language vs object model** -- Keep in mind that there are two components when using VBA - the **VBA language**, and the **object model** of the relevant Office program (in this case Microsoft Excel). Before asking a question, it's important to identify in which layer your issue is coming from.

**Debugging tools** -- The **VBA debugger and IDE** is very powerful, particularly for the beginner. Take the time to learn how to use it, and you will be better able to approach problems and ask relevant questions. Of particular note is the **Object Browser**, which lets you browse the various objects available in the referenced object models of your project, and their properties, methods and events.

**RTFM** -- Both [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264383.aspx) and Office object models (e.g. [Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ee861528.aspx)). have **extensive documentation**. I want to call out the following subsections:

- **How do I...** ([Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff820756.aspx), [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj692813.aspx)) -- step-by-step instructions on how to perform various tasks
- **Reference** ([Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194068.aspx), [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj692818.aspx)) -- *What can I do with an [`Excel.Workbook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835568.aspx)? Can I [close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838613.aspx) it? Can I get its [path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff840974.aspx)? Can I do something [after the user saves it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff836466.aspx)?*
- **Concepts** ([Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj733879.aspx), [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj692789.aspx)) -- broader overviews

Comment: @pnuts I've added the links to the [tag:excel-vba] wiki. Is there anything else here not already covered in the wiki?