# Programming Language Identification Questions

Tags: discussion, scope

I saw this question a few minutes ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651522/what-langauge-is-this-syntax

It started to get downvoted pretty quickly, which was curious to me.  I looked at the [language-identification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-identification) tag to see if this was the case for other questions.  (This tag is currently the question's only tag).  Whereas the tag is not highly used, the other questions did not suffer the same fate of downvotes, even though they are of similar content and format (ie- short, small code snippet, "What's this language?" as the only real txt).  The other questions are also relatively old at this point.

My thought is that the OP has just run across a handful of those in the community who didn't like it, but it made me wonder so I wanted to ask here.

Is this type of language identification question acceptable?

For those that can't see deleted question:

[image: question-screenshot]

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089531/what-language-is-this-program-written-in) is the "most famous" question tagged `language-identication`. As it is **pretty similiar** to the one you provided, I don't understand why one is -15 and the other well-downvoted (+17).

Comment: @Mistalis Yeah, exactly.  That was what sparked my curiosity and led to this question.

Comment: @Mistalis: Clearly the association with Stack Overflow's 404 page distinguishes that upvoted question from other random language identification questions.  That reason alone enables it to have value to future readers.  (Although arguably it ought to have been posted on Meta.)  Random "what's this programming language" questions have no such justification.

Comment: @kjhughes Agreed, that's what I tried to explain in [this burninate request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345129/lets-stop-language-identification).

Comment: see also: [Are "What is this thing called?" questions on-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277508/are-what-is-this-thing-called-questions-on-topic-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: For what it's worth, "language identification" is also a task in text processing, where you sometimes need to idintify the human language of a piece of text (English, Russian, Japanese, etc).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

How could this question ever possibly be useful?

Who's going to find a question like this?  Even if someone else has virtually identical code, they're still not going to find this question.  They couldn't; there's nothing in the question (or any possible answer) that's going to be searchable by anyone else with an even remotely similar problem.

Comment: A very fair point, and I agree.  But things like these made me wonder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089531/what-language-is-this-program-written-in and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316001/what-language-is-this.  So maybe it is that the community has turned the corner and recognizes this as low quality now.

Comment: @squillman Sure, and some people will upvote questions that entertain them, regardless of their usefulness, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @squillman I would say neither of them linked questions are useful to be honest. Questions asking to identify code are often snippets specific to the OP so they aren't useful to the community as a whole. It's like me asking _What's `Dim thisCode As String = "code"`? Looks like VB.NET? Is it?_ It isn't useful to anyone other than me. I mean look at how old they are and how many views they've had. Considering the age that isn't a lot of views.

Comment: language-identification tag, why does it even exist then ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Because someone who didn't know better added it.  Just like 90% of all of the tags on the site.  The existence of a tag doesn't mean that the content the tag describes is on topic, or that it would be useful, it just means that someone created the tag when writing one of said questions that doesn't belong.

Comment: Maybe... User should not be able to create tag, or tag creation should be verified and accepted by moderators before we can use them ? Maybe it's by design...

Comment: @AntoinePelletier That doesn't really scale all that well to the scope of content on the site.

Comment: Possible uses: I have inherited a code base to maintain, with little to no support--what OTS do I need to install to get this working? What technology do I need to learn?  I failed a computer-related certification test and need to know what to study to pass next time.  (All real-world examples experienced by me, coworkers, and my wife).  That said, I would say the question may need editing to add more context, to be useful (or discover-able).

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 Okay, so, given that you just inherited a code base, how do you expect to find this SO question with it's similar code in the same language?  How do you know that it's the same language and not a similar, but slightly different language?

Comment: @Servy Context or a larger snippet would definitely help.  Sure, this may never be a slam-dunk, and you're right, trial-and-error (in the inherited code base case) may be the only way to figure it out for sure.  But other than pulling your hair out or giving up in frustration, relevant content *somewhere* on the internet beats no content anywhere, and something like symbolhound might get you close.  Is SO the place for such content to find a home?  Well, I guess that's we're trying to figure out.

Comment: As it is off-topic, I've created a [burninate request for this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345129/lets-stop-language-identification).

Comment: Could you not make this searchable? Replace the question "what language is this syntax?" with "What server-side language has brace-percent signs as a delimiters in html?" (followed by the example).

Comment: I found it searching `"{% extends "_layouts/default" %}" site:stackoverflow.com` in Google, it was the first result :P

Comment: @ThomasYates And do you find it when you provide very similar, but not *textually identical* code?

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 This question is adding no more value to someone searching for answers on this topic than any information anywhere on the whole internet that's discussing that language.  Just about any question about anything related to the topic is going to contain some amount of code and at least mention the language, which is just as useful as this (which isn't very useful to begin with).  A question like this isn't adding value on top of that.

Comment: @Servy it depends on what I remove. If I remove `default` or `_layouts`, yes. If I remove them both, no, I didn't look further than the 3rd page when I tried that, but who does anyway. I can understand these questions being valuable when the code comes from a well-known framework, many people may ask themselves the same question about the same piece of code, but not from random code snippits.

Comment: I agree with Servy, if you just inherited a code base, and you have to figure out how to fix it, you will have to learn it the hard way anyway so... making a question about it is useless, since there are tons of other question using the said language... don't ask here. Search with google and find code snippits from everywhere to figure out.

Comment: For whatever it is worth, after I posted the question, I was given a very helpful answer and I was able to get on the right track.  I understand the question may not be searchable or help others but without  the help of the quick responses, I would have to research else where.  I think it is ok to down vote it or remove the OP; but I think there should be a tag/area where developers can ask questions to other experts for quick simple responses.

Comment: @Arcadian And yet the site doesn't exist for people to post questions that can only ever help them.  It's specifically designed to *not* be that.  It's designed to create a repository of knowledge that makes the internet a better place by improving the information avaliable for all programmers searching for answers to their questions.  It's not a free private tutoring service or a free consulting service.  If you want someone to tutor you, or a consultant to help you with your work, hire one.  SE isn't the place to get such services.

Answer (score -7):

- Stack Overflow is a site for programmers.
- In order to be a programmer, you must know at least one program language. Or if you are a would-be programmer ("enthusiast"), at least know the basics of one programming language.
- Questions of the form "what is this?" followed by source code, with no context, cannot per definition have been posted by a programmer of that language, or they would know what language it was.
- Therefore such questions are off-topic, for the same reasons as questions of the nature "what is programming?" or "what is the *x* programming language?" are off-topic.

Comment: *Questions of the form "what is this?" [...] cannot per definition have been posted by a programmer of that language, or they would know what language it was. Therefore such questions are off-topic.* -> Well, I don't think this is *why* those questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Mistalis Why not? How can a non-programmer ever post something that is on-topic for this site?

Comment: I think, those questions are off-topic because they won't help anyone except the OP, not for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: @Mistalis There is no "too localized" criteria on Stack Overflow any longer. [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252034/where-did-too-localized-go). It was removed during the "shittify Stack Overflow" close vote reform couple of years ago, together with "OP must have minimum knowledge of the topic".  The same reform encourages homework questions etc.

Answer (score -9):

We should keep this question and others like it. "hard to Google a similar question" is not an explicit reason for closing something. The close reasons people have used to remove this question and others like it are clearly wrong - e.g. "Unclear what you're asking" or "Too broad".

Sure, it's an implicit reason, but we can't easily tell whether a particular fragment of syntax will be a common enough idiom to steer Google here, or might become so in the future.

Clear lines between "on-topic" and "off-topic" make it much easier to use the site as a asker, answerer or reviewer.