# Let's stop [language-identification]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

This burninate request is based on [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345091/programming-language-identification-questions). I really suggest you read it, to understand why this tag is off-topic.

[language-identification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-identification)

> This tag can be used when the question contains code of an unknown
> code language, but can also be used to ask for similarities between
> languages.

There are <strike>18</strike> **0** questions tagged [language-identification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-identification), and only <strike>3</strike> **0** with only this tag. Due to the meta effect, some of those questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651522/what-langauge-is-this-syntax), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316001/what-language-is-this), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494508/recognizing-language-of-a-short-text)...) have already been put on-hold as off-topic/too-broad. One of the "popular" question on this tag is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089531/what-language-is-this-program-written-in) (*+16, 1k views*), probably famous because it tries to identify the language of the 404 Stack Overflow page.

## Why is that off-topic?

Just quoting [*@Servy's answer*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345092/4927984):

> How could this question ever possibly be useful?
>
> Who's going to find a question like this? Even if someone else has
> virtually identical code, they're still not going to find this
> question. They couldn't; there's nothing in the question (or any
> possible answer) that's going to be searchable by anyone else with an
> even remotely similar problem.

Comment: Opened to any proposal of [punny title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests), I was not very inspirated...

Comment: I've removed the tag from two of the questions: they were using it for how to programmatically identifying the language a text is written in or the language Excel is used with. So 16 questions left.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Same for [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317435/enforce-standardization-of-encoding-for-user-input-file-reader-input). I've updated the counter in the question.

Comment: It's just 15 question, we really have to do such cumbersome process?

Comment: Let's obfuscate [language-identification]?

Comment: Interesting. Example 3 does not sound like too broad or off-topic to me. It's an algorithm question similar to "how to identify if point is inside a polygon". Though the tag has been removed from that question

Comment: Dammit. Someone burned the "famous" one just as I was reading the answer! Is the explanation from the original author available anywhere else? If not, can it be?

Comment: @Vlad274 [Here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all questions have been cleaned, we can say that [language-identification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-identification) is

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here's the problem I see here: none of this is helpful to anyone except the OP.

> Help! What language is this?
>    [dumps code]

So they get an answer. Another user happens along... but that's not what *my code* looks like (even if it's the same language!). So they do the same thing. And on, and on, and on... Soon we have dozens of questions that aren't helping anyone except the OP. That wouldn't be a problem (there's probably millions of SO questions that might possibly help only the OP) if the subject matter didn't guarantee that would be the result. I can't Google my code sections and expect to pull up your question in this tag.

I say we burninate the tag, and migrate the [famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089531/what-language-is-the-program-on-stack-overflows-404-page-written-in) (Community Manager thing due to age) to Meta.SO (since it really is a meta question and worth keeping)

Comment: That question doesn't need migrated. The exact same answer [already exists on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code).

Comment: @animuson Ah, good to know

Answer (score -5):

I'll play devil's advocate here.  Though clearly this is not a popular tag, these are some examples of ways in which it could be useful (mostly copied from comments on the linked discussion).  Possible uses of the language-identification tag:

- I have inherited a code base to maintain, with little to no support--what OTS do I need to install to get this working?
- What technology do I need to learn to understand this system? (E.g.: some mysterious includes or scripting in an HTML page).
- I failed a computer-related certification test and need to know what to study to pass next time. (This example in question was a business education certification test, in which my wife was surprised to find computer code on the test.  I said "well, what language was it?" and she was like "how should I know?")

All of these are real-world examples experienced by me, coworkers, or my wife.

> Okay, so, given that you just inherited a code base, how do you expect
>   to find this SO question with it's similar code in the same language?
>   How do you know that it's the same language and not a similar, but
>   slightly different language?

*(Props to [@Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) for the counter-point comment)*

Context or a larger snippet would definitely help. Sure, this may never be a slam-dunk, and you're right, trial-and-error (in the inherited code base example) may be the only way to figure it out for sure. But other than pulling your hair out or giving up in frustration, relevant content *somewhere* on the internet beats no content anywhere, and something like Symbolhound might get you close (And thanks [@Thomas Yates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5557841/thomas-yates) for figuring out in the discussion that `"{% extends "_layouts/default" %}" site:stackoverflow.com` in Google easily found the SO question under discussion [...now deleted]).

Is SO the place for such content to find a home? Well, I guess that's what we're trying to figure out.

Comment: None of those real world examples would be on topic

Comment: @TinyGiant I was reading through [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) trying to validate your claim, but was having trouble coming up with something concrete.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: All of them would be too broad, and none of them would be any use to anyone other than the person asking the question, which is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score -13):

This burninate request should be discussed after it is figured out whether such questions are on-topic and/or useful. Not during. This is bad process. Just because there is one answer (which is still being disputed in the comments) which the OP accepted does not mean that it is suddenly the case. If it is determined to not be useful then by all means go ahead with the burninate, but don't jump the gun until then.

Comment: The point of this question (and the many others) is to get more eyes on those questions to argue about its value. And that can go both ways: the questions are crap or the tag doesn't help in categorizing and everything between. That is also stated in the tag wiki for [tag:burninate-request]: *Use in case of uncertainty when requesting discussion, or when the popularity of the tag makes manual retagging followed by automatic culling of 0-question tags prohibitively difficult.* and *Please do not start retagging before community consensus is reached*. Nobody jumps the gun here.