# Is a question asking for help identifying a programming language acceptable?

Tags: discussion

I need to find out what programming language a software ([IRAF](http://iraf.noao.edu/)) is written in.

Can I ask this question at SO, or is this considered off-topic?

**ADD**

I just found this related question [Programming Language Identification Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345091/programming-language-identification-questions?rq=1), which points to the answer being *no* (also, the fact that the `language-identification` tag has apparently been deleted).

In my case, I'd ask about a heavily used astronomical software, not just a snippet of code. Not sure if this changes anything?

BTW, I've tried this service

https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/PetiteProgrammer/ProgrammingLanguageIdentification

but it failed miserably.

Comment: Why not download the source package and see what it contains?

Comment: @BDL I did. It looks like `C`, but not quite. I'm not a `C` programmer, so I couldn't say precisely what makes it different.

Comment: Maybe you should check out a C chat room or similar. There are places on the internet for queries like that, but Stack Overflow is not one of those places.