# How to improve this question? Is it too broad? On wrong site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034939/ensure-integrity-of-large-number-of-files and I'd like some advice on how to improve it.

I described what I thought would be a fairly common use case and asked for advice on how it is normally handled.

I assumed this is a well known problem with a best practice solution, but I can't seem to find a standard approach to it (either particular methodology or software).

If it turns out that my assumption is wrong, then I'll have to build something myself, hence I added the part about Python which depends on the first part.

I can see that there are kind of 2 questions here, but they're dependent on each other so I asked together.

The question has been downvoted and there's a comment saying it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. I had considered that before posting and I disagreed, but clearly I'm wrong because I'm not getting any responses.

Should I split this into 2 separate questions, such as:

1. "I'm trying to ensure the integrity of a file archive but I don't know what terminology to use when researching it. What is my requirement called? Is it really a common use case or am I wrong?"
2. A design question around developing a tool to hash all the files in a tree and validate them later.

If so, where should I put them? I can see that asked on its own, #1 probably doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. Is it Server Fault? Super User? I see it as a business requirement more than a consumer one.

Would #2 clearly belong on Stack Overflow or Software Engineering, or does it depend on the exact question I end up asking?

Comment: I counted a total of 9 questions (including the 5 summary questions) in your post, you *don't* think that's a little bit too broad?

Comment: It's too broad in my opinion. It's very much nontrivial to program such a thing yourself. If you want a program that can do this, try [softwarerecs.se] after reading their on-topic and how-to-ask sections (you'd need to narrow down the scope a bit for softwarerecs)

Comment: If you are trying to ask **1**, why did you write that wall of text? Why didn't you just ask for **1** directly? Question **2** is not clear, but it doesn't seem like good question for SO, and if added to **1** it would make the whole thing bad. (And asking multiple question per question it's very easy to get the question perceived as _too broad_).

Comment: The problem is it's hard to describe. I've tried to re-word the question a few times to make it clearer what I'm asking

Comment: The first comment on your question says pretty much what's wrong with it. Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask how you would go about creating a project. It's for asking questions about specific problems you have during a process that you've already started.

Comment: Also, the first half of the question reads a lot more like something for SuperUser. Your idea that you might want to create a program to do what you want seems like an afterthought.

Comment: ok there seems to be pretty clear consensus that I should not have asked the second part to the question. It's also clearer now that it doesn't belong on SO. I'll try to just ask the first part somewhere

Comment: @ErikA the thing is, I'm not asking for a Software Recommendation. I'm just trying to find out what this thing would be called.  I guess asking on SR might be a good next step though

Comment: [Are “What is this thing called?” questions on-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277508/are-what-is-this-thing-called-questions-on-topic-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: wrt Software Engineering, see guidance at their meta: [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6504/31260)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless your question is specifically addressing a problem you are encountering while trying to solve this file integrity problem *through programming*, the question is off-topic.

- If your question isn't directly about programming or tools used for programming, it is not on topic. Tools in this case means that questions about compilers, IDEs, linkers, debuggers, version control, DBMS etc. Not computers, files, backup and severs.
- Questions about computers, files, backups, OS etc should be asked at https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/, whichever is applicable (read help -> on-topic per site before asking).
- Big picture programming issues, including "how do I do my whole project", are almost always too broad for this Q&A site.
- Questions about where to find information, tools or other off-site resources are off-topic.
- Questions about problems encountered when implementing this through programming need to be specific and narrowed down.