# Discussion. What arguments against the jargon tag can you provide?

Tags: discussion, tags

## Tags

Tags facilitate knowledge sharing by making questions easier to find. They also slightly increase the range of what is considered on-topic on Stack Overflow. Of course, tags alone cannot make something on-topic or off-topic. The question either is on-topic, or it isn't. We have the following tags:

- [terminology](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/terminology/info) – for questions about programming terms
- [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-lawyer/info) – for questions about language specifications
- [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info) – for questions that are not tied to any particular programming language

## Jargon vs. Terminology

I will try my best to explain the difference between these 2 words. Because there is a difference. Let's start with the easy one first. According to [Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/terminology), **terminology** is "the body of terms used with a particular technical application in a subject of study, profession, etc."

Programming terminology includes terms like: "function", "runtime", "data type", "method", "database", "dereferencing", "class", "object" etc. Yeah, I know, you're bored. Terminology is too easy to explain.

"Jargon" is a difficult word. Even dictionaries fail to do it justice. No wonder so many people misuse or misunderstand this word. Jargon includes, but it's not limited to, terminology. Jargon is overloaded language. I would even say it's a way of thinking. Right here on Stack Overflow I saw people using jargon without even realizing they were doing it. In fact, some even argued that it was "plain English"! Oh, by the way, when I said, "Jargon is overloaded language" did you thought that was plain English? According to [Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jargon), **jargon** is "special words or expressions used by a profession or group that are difficult for others to understand."

## The Jargon Beyond Terminology

I'm going to provide a few examples of programming jargon that is devoid of programming terminology. These are normal everyday English words that, when used in certain expressions, make no sense outside programming, or they make sense but mean different things in different fields. Some of these expressions sound innocent, others bend the rules of English grammar:

- "compares less than", "compares greater than", "compares equal to" etc.
- "physical structure of a program". What is this? We can talk about the physical structure of: buildings, boats, cars, bridges, transmission towers etc. As long as it can be physically broken apart, it has a physical structure. How could we possible talk about the physical structure of a program?
- "Physical Modeling" in the real world is the process of making a model of an object. For example, If the object is an aircraft, physical modeling will create an aircraft model like this:
  [image]

But in programming, "physical modeling" means different things in different areas. Are we talking about virtual simulation? Well, then you can use "physical modeling" to create virtual objects that obey the laws of physics. You can create a virtual piano and listen to how it sounds. You can create a virtual plane and test how it flies. You can create a flight simulator etc. But what if we're talking about databases? Well, then "physical modelling" means something completely different:

> Physical modeling involves the actual design of a database according
> to the requirements that were established during logical modeling.
> Logical modeling mainly involves gathering the requirements of the
> business, with the latter part of logical modeling directed toward the
> goals and requirements of the database. Physical modeling deals with
> the conversion of the logical, or business model, into a relational
> database model. When physical modeling occurs, objects are being
> defined at the schema level. A schema is a group of related objects in
> a database. A database design effort is normally associated with one
> schema. ([Rajan's Tech Corner](https://kalirajanl.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/logical-versus-physical-database-modeling/))

These expressions are not "programming terms". This is not terminology. This is jargon. "Jargon" is not some dirty word that needs to be censored and swept under the rug. Jargon exists because our sphere of knowledge expands much faster than our vocabulary. Particle physicists, for example, not only ran out of words, they ran out of Greek letters to name the new particles they discovered. Now they use the word "color" to refer to the charge of quarks and gluons. Richard Feynman said:

> The idiot physicists, unable to come up with any wonderful Greek words
> anymore, call this type of polarization by the unfortunate name of
> "color," which has nothing to do with color in the normal sense. (QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter, Princeton University Press, p. 136)

## Conclusion

The jargon tag should be used when a question asks for clarification regarding expressions that are outside the scope of the terminology tag. Of course, questions still have to meet the requirement to be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

More and more people rely on Stack Overflow to find answers to their questions about programming. Many times the solution to a problem is in the documentation or somewhere on the internet. Many times the source contains jargon, because language layers. So understanding programming jargon is essential to finding a solution to a problem. Programming jargon is inextricably linked to programming.

It is a well known fact that some use jargon as a social exclusion tool or as a way of showing off. The jargon tag will be a handy tool for those who want to tear down such esoteric walls.

I am aware that countless questions about jargon were deleted on Stack Overflow. But those questions were deleted because of their low quality and not simply because they were about jargon.

If necessary, the jargon tag may be used in conjunction with other tags. For example, if the user asks about C++ specific jargon, then the jargon tag should be accompanied by the C++ tag.

These are the type of questions that could benefit from the jargon tag:

- [Questions on simple threading jargon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3354766/7232508)
- [The term “Context” in programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6145091/7232508)
- [Difference amongst database jargon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43509265/7232508)
- [What is a non-jargon definition for WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6144798/7232508)
- [Please explain in the simplest, most jargon-free English possible, the “universal property of fold”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/841696/7232508)
- [What is the difference between a “Model” and a “Context” in Entity Framework jargon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18642203/7232508)

Comment: That smells like a meta-tag to me. Isn't that just the same as [tag:language-agnostic]?

Comment: Consider the [language-lawyer] tag.  It is preferentially applied to obfuscated language that appears in formal specifications, often the C++ standard.  Blog posts by Herb Sutter could squeak in, he convenes the ISO committee that sets the C++ standard.

Comment: Voting to Leave Open. The other question is about asking what to call one's identifiers in one's own code. This question is about jargon.

Comment: The votes to this question don't answer the "Would a jargon tag be useful?" question. They say that the question "Would a jargon tag be useful?" is useful or not. If you think the answer is no, *vote up the answer saying no*. Vote this question down *only if you think, talking about it is not useful* (what doesn't say anything about that this tag would be useful or not).

Comment: @HansPassant The [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-lawyer/info) tag should be used for questions regarding language specifications.

Comment: @rene Have you even read the [language-angostic](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info) tag info? That tag should be used in order to make it explicitly clear that the question is not tied to a particular programming language. I have edited my question to eradicate any such confusions in the future.

Comment: No, I have not. I leave random, unrelated comments on new meta posts. Works pretty well for me.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Isn't that some sort of malicious behavior on the part of gnat, Stephen Rauch, il_raffa, Robert Longson and Blackwood? I mean, obviously, my question has absolutely nothing in common, not even remotely, with the question, [Is it OK to ask for a “word-choice” on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277500/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-a-word-choice-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: @rene By all means, enlighten us about how the language-agnostic tag could be used to categorize and find questions about jargon. Also, a few arguments that could support your opinion that a jargon tag would necessarily be a meta-tag are more than welcome. You seem to be under the misapprehension that your reputation points allow you to be an encumbrance. This is not the right place to satisfy your need for drama. Lose that pretentious sarcasm and that [somebody is wrong on the internet](https://tinyurl.com/l54t7lv) attitude! If you can, try to provide constructive criticism, would you please?

Comment: I can live with *No* to my question: *Isn't that just the same as language-agnostic* there is no need for me to enlighten anyone. If all of you want that tag, be my guest. You make a pretty good case for the need of jargon. I honestly don't mind. I only wanted to verify if you considered any other tag.

Comment: As for the sarcasm and other nice words: I triggered on *did you even read*.  That has nothing to do with your or my reputation, I find such assumption that people don't read rude. But YMMV.

Comment: @rene What happened was that I read the info on the language-agnostic tag and I thought you were trolling me. That's how completely unrelated to jargon it is. That gave rise to the assumption that you haven't read the tag info. So my question, no matter how rude or rhetorical it may seem, was sincere. Making assumptions is OK as long as we don't base our conclusions on unverified assumptions. That's why I formulated my assumption as a question. I use questions both as an anger restraining tool and as an invitation to be proven wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback on how my comments are received. I'll take the lessons learned here going forward.

Comment: Im a bit curious why the tag [tag:jargon] now exists while the general concensus here seems that it wont be usefull???

Comment: First of all, how did you measure that consensus? All the people who downvoted this question misused their privilege. **The downvote should only be used** to bury a question that "does not show any research effort, is unclear or not useful". As **peterh** pointed out, you should not downvote a question because you think the answer to the question is "no". In fact, if you think this question even deserves an answer, you should actually upvote it. Right now, this question only has 1 answer with weak arguments. Most of the people who commented this question confused tags.

Comment: wow @q-l-p, you sure are trying really hard to tell everyone exactly how they have the right to interact with the world. could you please stop that? I don't think you have any say in how we vote, comment, or consider your requests.

Comment: As for consensus, yes, the votes is how we establish consensus on meta. You seem to value your own opinion much much more than that and decide that everyone is wrong, and that is not really nice. "All the people who downvoted this question misused their privilege." lol, you want everyone to check in with you so that supreme chancellor of the universe can approve their voting? Give me a break.

Comment: Just a quick comment here, I won't debate this, so if you respond to me I won't respond back. With that out of the way: I notice you only have this post on Meta, so... Welcome to Meta! If you have previous deleted posts, then welcome back to Meta! Just a quick note that you may or may not have known, but [voting is different on Meta.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) Generally, yes, people use votes on Meta to show opinions of a suggestion on Meta. Or: We're voting on how useful the _idea_ is. For example, users find the idea of a jargon tag not useful. Therefore, they downvote.

Answer (score 11):

I would say that a jargon tag is too meta and not really needed.

First of all, it's not clear from the tag name itself what it's about, what it encompasses. Is it a jargon of java? of C? Cobol? Delphi? php? assembly? A library? There is too much possible there that makes it simply not really useful as a tag to filter on.

We once had an experiment, Stack Overflow documentation that kind of tried to explain things but it didn't really fan out.

Also, the target audience is apparently aspiring beginners. Aspiring beginners should start with reading some books on the subject. The good old fashioned ones made of paper.

Those books usually have a thesaurus in the back explaining all jargon and have explanations in them what things need and are usually written in such ways that the reader is slowly introduced to all the needed background knowledge.

And even if they don't have books and learn everything from online, it's usually way more educational for a beginner to learn how to use Google to find the knowledge he seeks.

Stack Overflow can provide help in it, but that would be more suited by correct questions, with titles that can be easily found by newbies making queries like "What does runtime mean" and "What is a bitwise shift"

Comment: The jargon tag is similar to the terminology tag with the difference that the jargon tag deals with JARGON. All your objections against the jargon tag can be refuted by the same arguments that support the existence of the terminology tag. If you don't know the difference between jargon and terminology you should follow your own advice and... use the Google.If in a book there is some valuable information about programming that cannot be  found online then Stack Overflow is THE place to share that knowledge with others. Same thing with information found with Google.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to present the criteria for burnination and use those for this tag. Why? Because if a proposed tag meets the criteria for burnination, I would argue that means that the tag should not be created to begin with.

I will also present my opinions on the answers to these criteria questions and a "score" of whether the tag gives a "true" or "false" answer, at least as best I can. If you feel my answers are incorrect and the criteria would support a different position than my answers seem to, please, post your own answer elaborating on such.

*NOTE: I will not be comparing this to other tags. Arguing that tag "x" is fine, so this should be doesn't necessarily follow. It might instead beg the question of whether tag "x" should be burninated, if this tag is inappropriate but similar.*

I'm pulling these from the [Process for Burnination post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) which in turn gets them from MSE.

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is
>      applied? and is it unambiguous?

Well, "jargon" is certainly an unambiguous term. There's no denying that- If you're talking about jargon, most reasonable people are going to know what you're talking about. (Maybe not the specific jargon, but the word jargon definitely.)

As for the contents of the question... Well, I really don't think it would add any *useful* description of the contents of the question...

Overall, I'd give this a ".5" for this criteria, especially since I feel both questions in this point are covered in other points.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Really... I feel like it's too vague a concept to say "Yes, definitely" or "Heck no!" to this one. If you're strictly requesting what the jargon is, or what the jargon means... I'm not sure that would be on-topic, really, but I'm inclined to lean more towards the "maybe" side of things here.

I'll err on the side of caution and give this a ".5" as well.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. No it does not. If your question is about or contains jargon, you really don't even have to announce the fact. I really don't think anything meaningful is added to a post with this tag.

I give this tag a score of "0" for this point.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I would not hesitate to say yes, it most certainly does. No question there.

I give this point a "1" for score.

Overall, I would give this tag a score of 2/4 for the criteria.

---

Personally, I find that score to be bad for a tag. I also personally find the order of important of the points to be 3, 2, 4, 1, with a fail on 3 being a very bad sign. That, however, is my opinion and others are welcome to disagree.

Given the score of the tag for the list, per my own interpretation and feelings on the answers, I vote against the [jargon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jargon).